# How can I organize a few files that I work on into some sort of a custom Solution Explorer view in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a quite big solution with over 50 projects. Out of those I only use 2 which sit in opposite corners of the project list. In these 2 projects I only use a few files. Is there a way to get a view of only those files I am interested in across multiple projects in Visual Studio 2012 just like the Solution Explorer does but limited to my set of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ok, there is the standard feature named "Open Files Filter" that worked quite good for me. Basically in the Solution Explorer it shows only the files that are currently open. So as long as you don't close those tabs you will have the view with the same set of files it in.

   There is a shortcut that switches the Solution Explorer to the "Open Files Filter" mode: `Ctrl + [`, `O`
2. Another time saver is an option to start a new Solution Explorer by picking "New Solution Explorer View" in the context menu when you right click on a folder or project in the Solution Explorer.
3. Also the "Pending changes" filter in the top of the solution explorer also helps a lot.